# Show Ribbon on every page?

Tags: ribbon

I have done a custom tab and need to display it on every single page. But how? Ive tried with a delegate or feature control that adds an addition pageheader that runs some code getting the current Ribbon and making the the tab visible, it works, but only at pages only using the ribbon.

What makes the ribbon show initially in SharePoint be default when for example working with i list? It doesn't seem to be any code in the CMDUI.XML at least.

Ive alse tried adding a the PermissionStrings attribute to the Ribbon with the ViewPages value. Didn't make a difference though. :(

```
<SharePoint:SPRibbon PermissionsString="ViewPages" ID="SPRibbon1" runat="server" PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer" CssFile="" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the best and easiest solution will be available in version [1.4](http://spribbon.codeplex.com/releases/view/75638) of SharePoint 2010 Fluent Ribbon API
that [omlin](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/omlin) at codeplex runs.

[Blog post about the techique](http://amarkeev.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/sharepoint-add-ribbon-to-all-site-pages)

Thank you omlin!